# How to get a list of contacts in address book only that have a fax number?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to get a list of all contacts that have a fax number and only those contacts. Any contacts with just an email or just a phone number I do not want to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already you'll want to browse the [ABAddressBook Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)

Iterate through all the records of the address book, and get the `kABPersonPhoneProperty`.  This is a multivalue property, so iterate through all its labels.  If the work fax (`kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel`) or home fax (`kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel`) labels are present, get those values.

Here's some quick-n-dirty sample code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for( CFIndex personIndex = 0; personIndex < nPeople; personIndex++ ) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, personIndex );
    CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName( person );
    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue( person, kABPersonPhoneProperty );
    NSString* homeFax = nil;
    NSString* workFax = nil;
    BOOL hasFax = NO;
    for( CFIndex phoneIndex = 0; phoneIndex < ABMultiValueGetCount( phones ); phoneIndex++ ) {
        NSString* aLabel = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex( phones, phoneIndex );
        if( [aLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel] ) {
        homeFax = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex( phones, phoneIndex );
            hasFax = YES;
        }
        else if( [aLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel]) {
            workFax = (NSString*) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex( phones, phoneIndex );
            hasFax = YES;
        }
        [aLabel release];
    }
    if( hasFax ) {
        NSLog( @"%@: %@, %@", name, 
              homeFax == nil ? @"" : homeFax, 
              workFax == nil ? @"" : workFax );
        if( homeFax ) [homeFax release];
        if( workFax ) [workFax release];
    }
    CFRelease( phones );
    CFRelease( name );
}   

CFRelease( allPeople );
CFRelease( addressBook );
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to show an example. Most helpful.